# Is weak interaction the only interaction capable of changing the flavor of leptons?

Tags: standard-model, weak-interaction, leptons

I see this sentence in wiki about weak interaction:

> It is the only interaction capable of changing the flavor of quarks.

So why only quarks? Why not leptons? Is there another interaction which can change the flavor of leptons?

Comment: The same could be said of leptons. The wiki was just restrictions the statement to quarks.

Comment: The $W^\pm$ bosons flip the charge of quarks and leptons. This is the flavor changing weak interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The weak interaction does change the flavour of leptons. For example a muon decays to an electron through a weak interaction. The tree level diagram is:

[image: Muon decay]

([Image from Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon))

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to my question.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood what you are asking, but this is a weak interaction in which the muon number and electron number change so it changes flavour. Perhaps you could clarify what you mean. Are you looking for a single vertex with leptons of different flavour? If so I don't think any such process exists.

Comment: I am asking if weak interaction is the **only** interaction capable of changing lepton flavors. I wonder why wiki specifically says it is the **only** interaction capable of changing quark flavors but does not mention leptons.